# Using ng-repeat in filter

Tags: angularjs

I think popular question, but I don't found solution. Look e.g. I have object `{title:..., book:.... author:...}` and would like filter my view by title like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in main.products | filter: {{product.title}}">
  <span>{{product.author}}</span>
</div>
```

In `<span>` author has shown, but filter not working.

Comment: what is your mean about filter by title?what is filter value?

Comment: This is only simple example, but my point is I have courses maths, history etc. and I would sort all courses by title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get your filter value from server side, you can easily simulate it as:

```
 $scope.by_title = '';


  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.by_title = 'on';
  },3000);
```

and:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:{ title: by_title }">
```

<kbd>[DEMO PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/1L4Z2vAVpTmkndeB1Oeu?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This is great solution, by I don't want use input, I would like load data from database and filter

Comment: @V.R so what is a problem? replace `by_title` model with value comes from  server. Its the same behaviour

Comment: @V.R also if you get title filter from the server, please point it in your question. Its not clear

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, you should use `orderBy` filter for this.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in main.products | orderBy: 'title'">
```

Comment: can you create a demo?